# How to remove indentation on new line in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, codemirror

In my case, cursor jump through one empty line. How fix this? Thanks in advance.

In Angular 5 + Electron.

html:

```
   <codemirror
     [config]="{
       lineWrapping: true, 
       autofocus: true, 
       showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
       smartIndent: false
     }"
     (keyup.enter)="removeIndentation()"
     #novelEditor>
   </codemirror>
```

ts:

```
import { CodemirrorComponent } from 'ng2-codemirror';
...
@ViewChild('novelEditor') private novelEditor: CodemirrorComponent;
...
  removeIndentation() {
    const cm = this.novelEditor.instance;
    cm.replaceSelection("\n");
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
removeIndentation() {
   const cm = this.novelEditor.instance;
   cm.execCommand('delLineLeft');
}
```